# boxBufferGeometry doesn't show up in React three Fiber

Tags: javascript, three.js, react-three-fiber

This is the App.jsx file

```
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber"
import Experience from "./components/Experience"
function App() {
  return (
    <Canvas>
      <Experience />
    </Canvas>
  )
}

export default App
```

This is Experience.jsx file I add boxBufferGeometry and it is not workink

```
const Experience = () => {
    return (
        <mesh>
            <boxBufferGeometry />
            <meshNormalMaterial />
        </mesh>
    )
}

export default Experience
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `boxBufferGeometry` is now known as just `boxGeometry`